# Find a number in a vector with consecutive numbers

Tags: c++, vector

First, this is for my c++ class in high school and here is what the teacher did, when compiled and build there is no result,nothing is showed

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
  int V[50],n,x,f,li,ls,m,i;

  cout<<"number of elements=";
  cin>>n;
  cout<<"x=";
  cin>>x;

  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    cout<<"V["<<i<<"]=";
    cin>>V[i];
  }

  f=0;
  li=1;
  ls=n;

  while(li<=ls)&&(f==0);
  {
    m=(li+ls)/2;
    if(V[m]==x)
      f=1;
    else
      if(V[m]<x)
        li=m+1;
      else
        ls=m-1;
  }
  if(f==1)
    cout<<"the number is on position "<<m;
  else
    cout<<"the number is not in the vector";

  return 0;
}
```

I'm sorry about my bad english

Edit: i forogot, the example he gave us was:

```
V={ 5,5,5,6,7,7,8,8,8,9,10,10,25,25 }
```

and the `x=10`.

Comment: you have to post a code which actually compiles.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: one thing i corrected before i was able to run the program :

while(li<=ls&&f==0)

The question is..what is wrong with this code, how to make it work and show the position the number is in that vector or if it is in that vector

Comment: this while loop is terminated at the end of the line, not the block.
    while(li<=ls)&&(f==0);

Comment: suspectus: no, that's invalid syntax and won't compile.

Comment: @billz: `V[]`. Yes, it's not a `std::vector`. But since the code starts with `iostream.h` I guess this is what OP's teacher calls a vector. I'm out of here.

Comment: while(li<=ls&&f==0)
this is what i corrected to be able to compile 
And yes @Zeta..that's how we declare vectors...

Comment: @JohnSmith You might toss in a few cout's to follow the program flow, such as by following `li`, `ls`, and `m` through the loop. You might then tell your instructor that his variable names suck (they do suck, but don't tell him that). Finally... why does he never use element 0 of V? `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` ignores element 0, which should cost _you_ points if you did that, so why is he setting a bad example?

Comment: Because he is the general county inspector and he doesn't really have time for us he misses class and the variables names...they are initials for names of those variable from my country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Header import should be `#include <iostream>`
2. You need `using namespace std` after the header, or  use `std::cout` and `std::cin`
3. `while` expression should be `while((li<=ls)&&(f==0))`- it needs to be one expression without a semi-colon after it. Having `while(expr);` creates a loop that does nothing - `;` counts as an empty statement

Comment: thanks, the ; was the problem and the while expresion, it seems to be working fine now..